# TortoiseSVN: How do I merge a patched build and feature build into a new build?

Tags: svn, build, merge, tortoisesvn, visualsvn-server

Here's a diagram to illustrate the question:

[image: Diagram.]

I'm using TortoiseSVN to manage my repository, and VisualSVN Server to manage the repository remotely on a dedicated server. I learned how to do all of this by simply searching in Stack Overflow. Now I have come to a point where I don't know how to find an answer to this problem.

How can I merge a build with bug fixes and a build with new features together? If possible, can the answerer provide some instructions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think that you've meant "VisualSVN Server" not "VirtualSVN"

Comment: Yes, indeed. That is what I meant to say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `merge` option in TortoiseSVN to merge the two builds.
There are different types of merge options.

1. Merge a range of revisions
2. Reintegrate a branch
3. Merge two different trees

Perhaps, **Reintegrate branch** option will be useful for you, as this is used when you have created a feature branch from the trunk and after the feature is complete, you want to integrate it back to the trunk again.

This could be useful for you:

- [Reintegrate branch in TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-merge.html#tsvn-dug-merge-reintegrate) (TortoiseSVN manual),
- [Reintegrating a Branch](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html#svn.branchemerge.basicmerging.reintegrate) (Version Control With Subversion, the SVNBook).

Comment: Thanks for your help! I managed to work out each files individually and pick either one of the two given options.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding of your question is: You have two branches taken from a trunk / main branch. Now, you want to merge both these branches back to the main branch.

If this is the case, you could merge the branch with bug fixes using TortoiseSVN's merge option and resolve all the conflicts. Once this is done, you can merge the build with new features to the trunk / main branch.

Hope this helps....

Comment: Yes, it helped out. Thanks! :D User r9891 answered it with more instructions, so I choose that answer over you. Sorry.